# how to extract a dictionary from a data structure using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

so here is the table,  named grade_lists, that maps names of students to lists of their exam grades. The grades should be converted from strings to integers. For instance, grade_lists['Thorny'] == [100, 90, 80]. can someone help me?

```
 grades = [ #here is the table
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['Thorny', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['Mac', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['Farva', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['Rabbit', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
    ['Foster', '89', '97', '101']
]
```

Comment: Could you please share what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate through the list with `dict`:

```
grades_dict = dict((x[0],x[1:]) for x in grades[1:])
grades_dict
```

Output:

```
{'Farva': ['45', '56', '67'],
 'Foster': ['89', '97', '101'],
 'Mac': ['88', '99', '111'],
 'Rabbit': ['59', '61', '67'],
 'Thorny': ['100', '90', '80'],
 'Ursula': ['73', '79', '83']}
```

and `grades_dict['Thorny']`:

```
['100', '90', '80']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary-comprehension that maps values to integer:

```
{x[0]: list(map(int, x[1:])) for x in grades[1:]}
```

**Example**:

```
grades = [ #here is the table
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['Thorny', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['Mac', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['Farva', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['Rabbit', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
    ['Foster', '89', '97', '101']
]

print({x[0]: list(map(int, x[1:])) for x in grades[1:]})

# {'Thorny': [100, 90, 80], 
#  'Mac': [88, 99, 111],
#  'Farva': [45, 56, 67],
#  'Rabbit': [59, 61, 67],
#  'Ursula': [73, 79, 83],
#  'Foster': [89, 97, 101]}
```

This outputs a dictionary with name as key and  list of marks each converted to integer as value of that key.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this block of code.

```
grades = [ #here is the table
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['Thorny', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['Mac', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['Farva', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['Rabbit', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
    ['Foster', '89', '97', '101']
]
dict = {}
for student_data in grades:
   if student_data[0] == "Student":
     continue
   else:
     temp_list = []
     temp_list.append(int(student_data[1]))
     temp_list.append(int(student_data[2]))
     temp_list.append(int(student_data[3]))
     dict[student_data[0]] = temp_list

print(dict)
```

Comment: You appended `student_data[1]` thrice. Which will produce wrong output

Comment: Just fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner for the above problem:

`grades_dict = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1:]), grades))`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating though list and then converting it to dictionary, you can directly use dictionary comprehension. It's more Pythonic.

```
grades = [ #here is the table
    ['Student', 'Exam_1', 'Exam_2', 'Exam_3'],
    ['Thorny', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['Mac', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['Farva', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['Rabbit', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
    ['Foster', '89', '97', '101']
]
grade = {g[0]:g[1:] for g in grades[1:]}
print(grade)

# Output
#{'Thorny': ['100', '90', '80'], 'Mac': ['88', '99', '111'], 'Ursula': ['73', '79', '83'], 'Farva': ['45', '56', '67'], 'Foster': ['89', '97', '101'], 'Rabbit': ['59', '61', '67']}
```